# synopsys design compiler instance name missing generate prefix

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

When I synthesize below block of code, the name `mypfx` of the generate block doesn’t show up in the name of the register that gets inferred. I expect to see the register name look like `some_hierarchy_prefix/mypfx_0_test_latch_i`, but instead I see `some_hierarchy_prefix/test_latch_0_`. Why is that and how can I recode to get `mypfx` to show up in the register name?

```
logic [31:0] test_latch [31:0];
logic [31:0] test_data;
logic clock;

generate
  for(i = 0; i < 32; i++) begin : mypfx
    always_latch
     begin
        if (clock) test_latch[i] <= test_data;
      end     
  end : mypfx
endgenerate
```

Comment: `test_latch` is declared outside the generate block, it does not need to append for-generate block name `mypfx` to the latch. If some variables declared in the for-generate block, and they are not eliminated and are kept after synthesis optimization, then the block name and index need be appended to the variable to tell each individual same name variables generated by the for-generate block.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for mypfx to be a part of the instance name because of two reasons:

1. It can uniquely identify the 32 test_latch instances without using the mypfx prefix
2. There are no specific naming rules defined on test_latch to rename it in a particular way

You can do the following to have mypfx to be a part of the instance name

```
logic [31:0] test_latch;
logic [31:0] test_data;
logic clock;
generate
  for(i = 0; i < 32; i++) begin : mypfx
    always_latch
     begin
        if (clock) test_latch <= test_data;
     end     
  end : mypfx
endgenerate
```